# jde Gregorian date comparison

Tags: date, comparison, jde

Gregorian date comparison in crystal report. For example, if {@WO due date}< 7/18/2013 then XXX else XXX

When I check if there is an error, the system shows me that the "7/18/2013" is not a date, but I don't know what is the right format for the gregorian date for comparison. Would someone help me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if {@WO due date}< datea(7/18/2013)